# Scale SpriteNode from a Specific Point

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scale, skspritenode

When scaling a spriteNode to a smaller size (or larger size), the spriteNode by default scales from the centre, which is usually fine. However, I need my sprite to scale from the very left of it's body. Is there any way of changing the spriteNode's centre point so that I can achieved this?

I tried adjusting the anchor point of the spriteNode (below), which does scale from the left of the body, but it also repositions the spriteNode, which I do not want.

```
import SpriteKit

var mySprite: SKSpriteNode!

class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        mySprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 50))
        mySprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
        addChild(mySprite)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        mySprite.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 1))

    }
```

I was hoping for something like the below (which doesn't exist):

```
mySprite.centerPoint.x = -mySprite.size.width/2
```

Also, the below gets the result I want, but I don't really want to have to adjust the spriteNode position everytime I adjust the anchorPoint:

```
var mySprite: SKSpriteNode!

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        mySprite = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 50))
        mySprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
        mySprite.position.x = -mySprite.size.width/2
        addChild(mySprite)

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        mySprite.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 1))

    }
```

Comment: Depending on your sprite, you may wish to use center rect scaling where a middle portion of your sprite is the same, and when you scale, it keeps the edges and corners, but expands the middle.  [Apple describes this here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW10).

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete  `mySprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)` in `didload` and in  `touchesBegan`:

```
mySprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
func repositionAncorPoint() {
    mySprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
}
let resetAncor = SKAction.runBlock({ repositionAncorPoint() })
let rescale = SKAction.scaleTo(0.5, duration: 1)
let sequence = [rescale,resetAncor]
mySprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence(sequence))
```

I've not test it... :)